# why i'm getting the following error "Data truncated for column 'model' at row 1"

Tags: php, html, mysql, visual-studio-code

So I want to get the user data from the form and then store it in the database but i'm getting the error "Data truncated for column 'model' at row 1" when I try to add the details.

I am using the radio button so the user can pick 1 make and 1 model related to that make and then want those details to be added to the database under appropriate headings as in MySQL table table below

html form code:

```
<form action="Add.php" method="POST" class="form">
  <h2>Car Registration Form</h2>
  <div class="mb-3">


    <input type="radio" name="Car" id="Toyota" value="Toyota" />

    <label for="Toyota" class="form-label">Toyota</label>
    <select name="Models" class="form-control">
      <option value="">None</option>
      <option value="Camri">Camri</option>
      <option value="Corolla">Corolla</option>
      <option value="Estima">Estima</option>
    </select><br>

    <input type="radio" name="Car" id="Nissan" value="Nissan" />

    <label for="Nissan" class="form-label">Nissan</label>
    <select name="Models" class="form-control">
      <option value="">None</option>
      <option value="Micra">Micra</option>
      <option value="roller">roller</option>
      <option value="fushe">fushe</option>
    </select><br>

    <input type="radio" name="Car" id="Mercedez" value="Mercedez" />

    <label for="Mercedez" class="form-label">Mercedez</label>
    <select name="Models" class="form-control">
      <option value="">None</option>
      <option value="5series">5series</option>
      <option value="x7">x7</option>
      <option value="x5">x5</option>
    </select><br>



    <label for="vehicleidentificationnumber" class="form-label">vehicle identification number (VIN)</label>
    <input type="text" name="vehicleidentificationnumber" class="form-control" maxlength=20 required>

    <label for="ManufacturingYear" class="form-label">Manufacturing Year</label>
    <input type="text" name="ManufacturingYear" class="form-control" maxlength=20 required>

    <label for="Enginesize" class="form-label">Engine size</label>
    <input type="text" name="Enginesize" class="form-control" maxlength=20 required>

    <label for="Transmissiontype" class="form-label">Transmission type</label>
    <input type="text" name="Transmissiontype" class="form-control" maxlength=20 required>

    <label for="NoofSeats" class="form-label">No. of Seats</label>
    <input type="number" name="NoofSeats" class="form-control" maxlength=20 required>

    <label for="Noofdoors" class="form-label">No. of doors</label>
    <input type="number" name="Noofdoors" class="form-control" maxlength=20 required>

    <label for="Fueltype" class="form-label">Fuel type</label>
    <input type="text" name="Fueltype" class="form-control" maxlength=20 required>

    <label for="Colour" class="form-label">Colour</label>
    <input type="text" name="Colour" class="form-control" maxlength=20 required>

    <label for="RegistrationNumber" class="form-label">Registration Number (use Dublin registration) </label>
    <input type="text" name="RegistrationNumber" class="form-control" maxlength=20 required>

    <label for="Dateoffirstregistration" class="form-label">Date of first registration</label>
    <input type="date" name="Dateoffirstregistration" class="form-control" maxlength=20 required>

  </div>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="submit" name="insertdata" class="btn btn-primary">Add Car</button>


  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">

</form>
```

php code

```
require('/home/s3s/sqlC/dbConnect.php');

$Car = $_POST['Car'];
$Models = $_POST['Models'];
$vehicleidentificationnumber = $_POST['vehicleidentificationnumber'];
$ManufacturingYear = $_POST['ManufacturingYear'];
$Enginesize = $_POST['Enginesize'];
$Transmissiontype = $_POST['Transmissiontype'];
$NoofSeats = $_POST['NoofSeats'];
$Noofdoors = $_POST['Noofdoors'];
$Fueltype = $_POST['Fueltype'];
$Colour = $_POST['Colour'];
$RegistrationNumber = $_POST['RegistrationNumber'];
$Dateoffirstregistration = $_POST['Dateoffirstregistration'];


require('/home/s3022041/sqlC/dbConnect.php');
$query = "INSERT INTO cars (make, model, VIN, Manufacture_Year, Engine_Size, Transmission_Type, NoOfSeats, NoOfDoors, Fuel_Type, Colour, Registration_Number, DateOfRegestration) 
                VALUES ('$Car','$Models', '$vehicleidentificationnumber','$ManufacturingYear','$Enginesize','$Transmissiontype','$NoofSeats','$Noofdoors','$Fueltype','$Colour','$RegistrationNumber','$Dateoffirstregistration');";
$query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if ($query_run) {
    echo "<h2>Added successfully</h2>";
    echo "<a href='index.php'>home</a>";
} else {
    echo 'Error! '.mysqli_error($connection);
}
```

MySQL code

```
create table cars(
    make varchar(256) not null,
    model ENUM('Camri', 'Corolla', 'Estima', 'Micra', 'roller', 'fushe', '5series', 'x7', 'x5'),
    VIN varchar(256) not null,
    Manufacture_Year int(11) not null,
    Engine_Size int(11) not null,
    Transmission_Type varchar(256) not null,
    NoOfSeats int(11) not null,
    NoOfDoors int(11) not null,
    Fuel_Type varchar(256) not null,
    Colour varchar(256) not null,
    Registration_Number varchar(256) not null,
    DateOfRegestration Date not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (VIN)
);
```

Comment: It means that the column `model` is either not of the correct **type** or is limited in length IE `varchar(5)` --  You should check the column settings and change them accordingly.

Comment: so what do i change in column model ?

Comment: i am able to create the table successfully but not able to add the details?

Comment: You have multiple `<select name="Models">` elements. Only the last one will be sent in the form.

Comment: yeah but I wish to get the value of what user enter from any of the three models thats why I have three models

Comment: AND you have "None" as an `<option>` in your `<SELECT>` .. But not in your ENUM .

Comment: You need to give them different names. Then in the PHP you can decide which one to use based on the value of `$_POST['Car']`

Comment: Or you could use JavaScript to change the options in the dropdown depending on the radio button choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that PHP doesn't know that it should only use the value of `Model` from the dropdown below the selected radio button. It uses the value of the last one. If the user leaves that one unselected, the value `""` doesn't correspond to any of the ENUM values, so you get an error.

You can give them distinct names, and then select the appropriate one based on the radio button.

HTML:

```
<form action="Add.php" method="POST" class="form">
  <h2>Car Registration Form</h2>
  <div class="mb-3">


    <input type="radio" name="Car" id="Toyota" value="Toyota" />

    <label for="Toyota" class="form-label">Toyota</label>
    <select name="Models[Toyota]" class="form-control">
      <option value="">None</option>
      <option value="Camri">Camri</option>
      <option value="Corolla">Corolla</option>
      <option value="Estima">Estima</option>
    </select><br>

    <input type="radio" name="Car" id="Nissan" value="Nissan" />

    <label for="Nissan" class="form-label">Nissan</label>
    <select name="Models[Nissan]" class="form-control">
      <option value="">None</option>
      <option value="Micra">Micra</option>
      <option value="roller">roller</option>
      <option value="fushe">fushe</option>
    </select><br>

    <input type="radio" name="Car" id="Mercedez" value="Mercedez" />

    <label for="Mercedez" class="form-label">Mercedez</label>
    <select name="Models[Mercedez]" class="form-control">
      <option value="">None</option>
      <option value="5series">5series</option>
      <option value="x7">x7</option>
      <option value="x5">x5</option>
    </select><br>



    <label for="vehicleidentificationnumber" class="form-label">vehicle identification number (VIN)</label>
    <input type="text" name="vehicleidentificationnumber" class="form-control" maxlength=20 required>

    <label for="ManufacturingYear" class="form-label">Manufacturing Year</label>
    <input type="text" name="ManufacturingYear" class="form-control" maxlength=20 required>

    <label for="Enginesize" class="form-label">Engine size</label>
    <input type="text" name="Enginesize" class="form-control" maxlength=20 required>

    <label for="Transmissiontype" class="form-label">Transmission type</label>
    <input type="text" name="Transmissiontype" class="form-control" maxlength=20 required>

    <label for="NoofSeats" class="form-label">No. of Seats</label>
    <input type="number" name="NoofSeats" class="form-control" maxlength=20 required>

    <label for="Noofdoors" class="form-label">No. of doors</label>
    <input type="number" name="Noofdoors" class="form-control" maxlength=20 required>

    <label for="Fueltype" class="form-label">Fuel type</label>
    <input type="text" name="Fueltype" class="form-control" maxlength=20 required>

    <label for="Colour" class="form-label">Colour</label>
    <input type="text" name="Colour" class="form-control" maxlength=20 required>

    <label for="RegistrationNumber" class="form-label">Registration Number (use Dublin registration) </label>
    <input type="text" name="RegistrationNumber" class="form-control" maxlength=20 required>

    <label for="Dateoffirstregistration" class="form-label">Date of first registration</label>
    <input type="date" name="Dateoffirstregistration" class="form-control" maxlength=20 required>

  </div>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="submit" name="insertdata" class="btn btn-primary">Add Car</button>


  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">

</form>
```

PHP:

```
$Car = $_POST['Car'];
$Models = $_POST['Models'][$Car];
if ($Models == "") {
    die("Error! You must select a model for $Car");
}
```

Comment: Also allowing for ENUM to 'null' and accepting a NULL value would also be acceptable.

Comment: @Zak Adding `""` as an ENUM value would be simpler.

Comment: ok @Barmar i have followed your html and php code above and its now working, thanks